# Eureka server with kubernetes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, netflix-eureka

Currently I have a Spring containers running in a Kubernetes cluster.  I am going through Udacity's Spring web classes and find the Eureka server interesting.

Is there any benefit in using the Eureka server within the cluster?

any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly an option question but ... probably not? The core Service system does most of the same thing. But if you're specifically using Eureka's service metadata system then maybe?